# Real part of complex exponential

Tags: complex, assumptions

How do you obtain the real part of a complex exponential? For example, Mathematica gives $Re[e^{ik}]$ instead of $\cos(k)$, see figure.

```
In: $Assumptions = {k > 0}
Out: {k > 0}
In: Simplify[Re[Exp[(I*k)]]]
Out: Re[E^(I k)]
```

[image: example]

Comment: Try [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) instead of [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html).

Comment: `ComplexExpand` assumes that all variables are real if not declared otherwise and expands the expression.

Comment: Does Mathematica assume k to be real if you specify $k>0$? Or do you have to write `$Assumptions = {k>0 && Element[k, Reals]}`?

Comment: `k > 0` already implies `Element[k, Reals]`, yes.

Comment: @Frederic Here's some background on J.M.'s comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field

Answer (score 1):

You may do it this way:

```
Re[Exp[(I*k)]] // ComplexExpand

(*  Cos[k]  *)
```

I often do it like this:

```
(Exp[(I*k)] // ExpToTrig) /. I -> 0

(*  Cos[k]   *)
```

Have fun!